# Trying to get the value of the buttons when i onclick here and store in an array? any idea what im doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to be able to onclick and select one of four buttons inside a div. 
The div is one of five - so when i click i only want to check the exact button and the right div to be effected by the attribute changes
The buttons are nested inside the divs as shown here. 
Can i use an eventhandler to confirm which div im clicking on and then use an if statement to control from there?

The final issue im having is that i want to push the innerHTML to an array to then check against but i keep getting undefined error

HTML..........

```
 <div class="rightMain" id="q1box">
   <div class="answerButtonBox">
   <button type="button" class="answerButton" id="q1A" value="1">The Marauder</button>
   </div>
   <div class="answerButtonBox">
   <button type="button" class="answerButton" id="q1B" value="2">The Black Pearl</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Typescript/JS....

```
    var userGuess:[{}];       ///can i just initilize an array and then push the innerhtml into it?
    var answers: [{}];


    question1.addEventListener("click", checkq1)

    function checkq1(){
    if (first.onclick)
    {
        first.setAttribute("style", "background-color: yellow;")
        second.setAttribute("style", "background-color: grey;")
        third.setAttribute("style", "background-color: grey;")
        fourth.setAttribute("style", "background-color: grey;")
        userGuess.push(first.innerHTML)
    }
    if (second.onclick)
    {
        first.setAttribute("style", "background-color: grey;")
        second.setAttribute("style", "background-color: yellow;")
        third.setAttribute("style", "background-color: grey;")
        fourth.setAttribute("style", "background-color: grey;")
        userGuess.push(second.innerHTML)
    }

etc.....
```

Any help would be appreciated!

the error im getting with respect to my array....

index.ts:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.checkq1 (index.ts:59)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all not-selected answer and get css for it, hope it helps

```js
const answerBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('answerButton');
for (var i = 0; i < answerBtn.length; i++) {
    answerBtn[i].addEventListener('click', getAnswer, false);
}
function getAnswer() {
    const selectAnswer = this;
    selectAnswer.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: yellow;');
    const parent = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    const notSelectedAns = [];
    for (i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
        if (parent.children[i].firstElementChild !== selectAnswer) {
            notSelectedAns.push(parent.children[i].firstElementChild);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < notSelectedAns.length; i++) {
        notSelectedAns[i].setAttribute('style', 'background-color: grey;');
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="rightMain" id="q1box">
 <div class="answerButtonBox">
 <button type="button" class="answerButton" id="q1A" value="1">The Marauder</button>
 </div>
 <div class="answerButtonBox">
 <button type="button" class="answerButton" id="q1B" value="2">The Black Pearl</button>
 </div>
<div class="answerButtonBox">
 <button type="button" class="answerButton" id="q1C" value="3">The Black Pearl</button>
 </div>
<div class="answerButtonBox">
 <button type="button" class="answerButton" id="q1D" value="4">The Black Pearl</button>
 </div>
</div>
```